# Fill pandas DataFrame nans with index value

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` which contains `nan` values. I would like to fill those `nan`s with the index value. The actual use case is filling the `nan`s with a string template containing the index value which you can answer as a bonus.

Given:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
          0         1         2         3
0       NaN  0.069419       NaN       NaN
1  2.439000  1.943944  0.279904  0.755746
2  0.013795  1.189474  0.834894  2.202108
3  0.520385       NaN       NaN  1.451822
4  0.153863  0.957394       NaN  0.052726
5  1.274204       NaN       NaN  0.169636
6       NaN  1.031703       NaN  0.267850
7  0.419157       NaN       NaN  0.409045
8       NaN  1.526764  0.947936  0.442226
9       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.458331
```

and

```
In [35]: tmp
Out[35]: 'i=%(idx)s'
```

Output should be something like the following:

```
          0         1         2         3
0       i=0  0.069419       i=0       i=0
1  2.439000  1.943944  0.279904  0.755746
2  0.013795  1.189474  0.834894  2.202108
3  0.520385       i=3       i=3  1.451822
4  0.153863  0.957394       i=4  0.052726
5  1.274204       i=5       i=5  0.169636
6       i=6  1.031703       i=6  0.267850
7  0.419157       i=7       i=7  0.409045
8       i=8  1.526764  0.947936  0.442226
9       i=9       i=9       i=9  0.458331
```

Just trying to fill the `nan`s with the index.

Tried

```
In [32]: df.fillna(df.index)

ValueError: invalid fill value with a <class 'pandas.core.index.Int64Index'>
```

Tried

```
In [33]: df.replace(np.nan, df.index)

TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'float'
```

Tried

```
In [41]: df.fillna(df.index.values)

ValueError: invalid fill value with a <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Tried

```
In [53]: df1 = df.astype(object)
```

and repeating the above, received same errors.

Using `pandas==0.17.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @maxymoo solution using `where` but with `pd.Series` instead of `lambda`:

```
s = pd.Series(['i={}'.format(i) for i in df.index])

In [49]: df.where(df.notnull(), s, axis=0)
Out[49]:
          0         1         2         3
0       i=0  0.069419       i=0       i=0
1     2.439   1.94394  0.279904  0.755746
2  0.013795   1.18947  0.834894   2.20211
3  0.520385       i=3       i=3   1.45182
4  0.153863  0.957394       i=4  0.052726
5    1.2742       i=5       i=5  0.169636
6       i=6    1.0317       i=6   0.26785
7  0.419157       i=7       i=7  0.409045
8       i=8   1.52676  0.947936  0.442226
9       i=9       i=9       i=9  0.458331
```

**Timing**:

```
def f1():
    nan_strings = ["i={}".format(i) for i in df.index]
    df.apply(lambda c: c.where(c.notnull(), nan_strings))

def f2():
    s = pd.Series(['i={}s'.format(i) for i in df.index])
    df.where(df.notnull(), s, axis=0)

In [51]: %timeit f1()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.17 ms per loop

In [52]: %timeit f2()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice one, +1 for `%timeit`

Comment: very nice, didn't know about using `axis` to broadcast across the columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where` to do your substitution (it's kind of like assignment with a  reversed mask), but you'll need to apply it column-by-column, I can't think of how to do it all at once:

```
In [1]: nan_strings = ["i={}".format(i) for i in df.index]

In [2]: df.apply(lambda c: c.where(c.notnull(), nan_strings))
Out[2]:
          0         1         2         3
0       i=0  0.069419       i=0       i=0
1     2.439   1.94394  0.279904  0.755746
2  0.013795   1.18947  0.834894   2.20211
3  0.520385       i=3       i=3   1.45182
4  0.153863  0.957394       i=4  0.052726
5    1.2742       i=5       i=5  0.169636
6       i=6    1.0317       i=6   0.26785
7  0.419157       i=7       i=7  0.409045
8       i=8   1.52676  0.947936  0.442226
9       i=9       i=9       i=9  0.458331
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you are doing is going to cause problems. Firstly, your columns appear to be all `float64`. `'i=%(idx)s'` is a string. So you will either have to convert all columns to `object` or you will have to fill float values for `nan`. That said, why don't you try this, and let me know if you get your answer:

```
df.fillna(df.index.values, inplace=True)
```

---

Since you say bonus, let's try to convert the columns to `object` type first:

```
fill_val = ['i={}'.format(i) for i in df.index.values]
df.astype('object', inplace=True)
df.fillna(fill_val, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Should have noted I tried using index values, does not like numpy arrays: `ValueError: invalid fill value with a <type 'numpy.ndarray'>` Understood on the float v. object.

Comment: You can do this in one line: `df.astype(object, inplace=True)`

Comment: @strimp099:  That error can be fixed if you convert it to list: `list(df.index)`. I'm still Pandas 0.13 guy! Haha, that's when I started, haven't kept up with the changes in all functions.

Comment: Tell me about it mate, started with 0.03 :)